Movie with blond short-haired girl who wears a tan leotard and lives near the sea
I'm looking for a title of a movie. It more or less centers around a girl with a blond buzz-cut with blue eyes. She wears a tan / flesh color leotard throughout.
I also remember scenes around the beach, and one in which she jumps off a cliff into the water. There was also a male lead actor, who jumps into the ocean after her. 
I can't say when the movie was made but judging from the grain of the film maybe 70-80's. The movie could've been from the 90's too.
I very vaguely remember the lead actress not being entirely human, but an incarnation of something.
The movie was not black and white.

Please provide any more info you can remember like any other minor plot or actor , year approx it was released and where you watched.

You might be thinking of The Icicle Thief, (1989).  In the poster for the film you can see the woman with the blonde buzz cut sort of diving into water.  She is "not entirely human" in that she is a character from a color commercial who has found herself in the b&w movie in which the commercial was shown.


No, this isn't it, but looks really interesting! The movie was not in black and white.

Splash - the lead is a mermaid and it's Tom hanks that dives in after her. The female actress has had her hair chopped in movies before, maybe even in Splash, but if not then that's the confusion. 
